# Foreach loop only working on last item

Tags: comments, arrays, foreach

What I'm trying to do is find the URL's in comments and then check those URL's against an array. If the URL is in the array and has the key 'data' with a certain value then I want to replace each URL in the comment with custom text.

I have everything working except the replacing part. This is what I have so far.

the comment

```
Lorem www.link1.com and ipsum dolor sit amet, http://link2.com consectetur
adipiscing elit. Maecenas http://link3.com eu tempor nibh.
```

The array the function is using

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 200
            [data] => one
            [url] => www.link1.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => 204
            [data] => 
            [url] => http://link2.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => 200
            [data] => two
            [url] => http://link3.com
        )
)
```

the function

```
function check_the_status( $arrays, $comment ) {
    // Bad statis types
    $status = apply_filters( 'status_filter', array( 'one', 'two', 'three' ) );
    $modified = '';
    foreach( $arrays as $key => $array ){
        $url = $array['url'];
        $data = $array['data'];
        if( in_array( $data, $status ) ) {
            $modified = '<span>the new text</span>';
            $the_comment = str_replace( $url, $modified, $comment );
        }
    }
    return $the_comment;
}
```

the output

```
Lorem www.link1.com and ipsum dolor sit amet, http://link2.com consectetur
adipiscing elit. Maecenas "<span>the new text</span>" eu tempor nibh.
```

So, what's happening with this function, is it's only applying the new text to the last URL in the array, but I want it to be applied to the first and last URL's because they both have the data value I'm checking for in the array. I'm thinking the foreach loop isn't the right way to achieve what I want, but I'm not sure what's the best way.

Comment: You need to rethink how you build your array. Not really a Wordpress issue. The answer given should give you the minimum needed

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with the following line. You are starting over with each iteration by passing $comment each time:

```
$the_comment = str_replace( $url, $modified, $comment );
```

You should change it to:

```
$the_comment = str_replace( $url, $modified, $the_comment );
```

and intialize $the_comment before the loop:

```
$the_comment = $comment;
```

Based on additional comments, here's the working code. I added "bold" style so the result is more pronounced.

```
    $arrays = Array
    (
        0 => Array
            (
                'status' => 200,
                'data' => 'one',
                'url' => 'www.link1.com'
            ),

        1 => Array
            (
                'status' => 204,
                'data' => '',
                'url' => 'http://link2.com'
            ),

        2 => Array
            (
                'status' => 200,
                'data' => 'two',
                'url' => 'http://link3.com'
            )
    );

    function check_the_status( $arrays, $comment ) {
        // Bad statis types
        $status = apply_filters( 'status_filter', array( 'one', 'two', 'three' ) );
        // The class for targeting the url
        $span_class = apply_filters( 'status_class', 'sl-unsafe-link' );
        $modified = '';
        $the_comment = $comment;
        foreach( $arrays as $key => $array ){
            $url = $array['url'];
            $data = $array['data'];
            if( in_array( $data, $status ) ) {
                $modified = '<span style="font-weight:bold">'.$url.'</span>';
                $the_comment = str_replace( $url, $modified, $the_comment );
            }
        }
        return $the_comment;
    }

    $comment = 'Lorem www.link1.com and ipsum dolor sit amet, http://link2.com consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas http://link3.com eu tempor nibh.';
    $new = check_the_status($arrays, $comment);
    echo $new;
```

I ran it locally and this is the output:

```
Lorem <span style="font-weight:bold">www.link1.com</span> and ipsum dolor sit amet, http://link2.com consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas <span style="font-weight:bold">http://link3.com</span> eu tempor nibh.
```

Comment: That almost did it, now the span is being added twice

Comment: It should be added twice according to the logic though, shouldn't it? For array element 0 and 2?

Comment: That's not my intent, I'm sure the foreach is not the right way, but I'm not sure how to do it. I want to iterate throw the array and if an entry if the data has one of the values I'm looking for. Then wrap a span around the URL in the comment text.

Comment: Foreach should be fine for that. To wrap a span around the url you would just use this: $modified = '<span>'.$url.'</span>'.  Also remove the echo command.  (Otherwise you may want to edit your question to clarify what it is exactly you are trying to accomplish.)

Comment: I updated the answer with the working code. I'm not sure how you are getting the double span tags.

Comment: td-lambda the echo shouldn't have been there I edited it out. But the the span is being added twice. I only want added once. The URL is being wrapped like <span><span>theurl</span></span>

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that code is still causing the span twice. Thanks for the $comment fix though. I'll figure it out somehow.

Comment: Not a problem, you must somehow be running the same comment through the method twice, that is the only way i can think of this happening.